# Removing all extra white spaces apart from New Line - Regex in Power Automate Desktop

Tags: regex, power-automate

Having difficulty with Power Automate Desktop, trying to convert this:

```
OS Name : Microsoft Windows 10   Pro
System Name :    DESKTOP-VHCTR2M
Processor : Intel(R)      Core(TM) i7 CPU         920  @ 2.67GHz, 2668 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 8 Logical Processor(s)
BIOS Version/Date : American Megatrends Inc. 0504, 19/05/2009
BaseBoard Manufacturer : ASUSTeK Computer   INC.
BaseBoard Product : P6T DELUXE   V2
Platform Role : Desktop
Secure Boot State : Unsupported
Installed Physical Memory (RAM) : 32.0 GB
```

Remove all extra white spaces but keep the new line so the outcome would look like this:

```
OS Name : Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
System Name : DESKTOP-VHCTR2M
Processor : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU 920 @ 2.67GHz, 2668 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 8 Logical Processor(s)
BIOS Version/Date : American Megatrends Inc. 0504, 19/05/2009
BaseBoard Manufacturer : ASUSTeK Computer INC.
BaseBoard Product : P6T DELUXE V2
Platform Role : Desktop
Secure Boot State : Unsupported
Installed Physical Memory (RAM) : 32.0 GB
```

So all text has 1 white space and not random spaces.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please share what you've tried so far. You say you're having difficulty, but not what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[^\S\r\n]{2,}

This seems to work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).